# Solana SPL token transfer with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, transactions, solana

So after having read a couple of articles I'm yet to understand how to create a Transaction and send custom SPL tokens across the Solana blockchain.
I've attached my code below. 
I truly don't understand what each part of the transaction is supposed to be. 
So I figured that `owner` is the account/wallet that is sending and paying for the transaction. And I'm assuming that `dest` is where I wish to send the tokens to. 
[This](https://solscan.io/token/DCzbhHu3YGnc8Vhez4YEMznQ38ad6WYGVYqeB4Wn3mie?cluster=devnet) is the token (on devnet) that I wish to send, But I don't seem to be able.

```py
from spl.token.constants import TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
from spl.token.instructions import transfer_checked, TransferCheckedParams

from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solana.keypair import Keypair
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.transaction import Transaction

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

class TransferService:
    def __init__(self, client: Client, service: SolanaService, token) -> None:
        self.client = client
        self.service = service
        self.keypair = self.service.get_keypair(token)

    def make_transaction(self, source, mint, dest, owner, amount=1, decimals=0) -> Transaction:
        transaction = Transaction()
        transaction.add(transfer_checked(
            TransferCheckedParams(
                program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                mint=PublicKey(mint),
                source=PublicKey(source),
                dest=PublicKey(dest),
                owner=owner,
                amount=amount,
                decimals=decimals,
                signers=[]
        )))
        return transaction

    def send_transaction(self, transaction) -> None:
        self.client.send_transaction(
            transaction,
            self.keypair,
            opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment=Confirmed)
        )

load_dotenv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
    client = Client('https://api.devnet.solana.com')
    service = SolanaService(client)
    token = os.getenv('KEYPAIR')
    transfer = TransferService(client, service, token)
    a = client.get_account_info(transfer.keypair.public_key)
    transaction = transfer.make_transaction(
        source='CtURxXpzn9aredXse2KNtyDMeVW627tL3p7DCucdv8bc',
        mint='DCzbhHu3YGnc8Vhez4YEMznQ38ad6WYGVYqeB4Wn3mie',
        dest='sPkypr2LBtF5Go87zYSn5fBtWxCDEcobWeQQxXHpxJR',
        owner=transfer.keypair.public_key,
        amount=1,
        decimals=9

    )
    transfer.send_transaction(transaction)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination `sPkypr2LBtF5Go87zYSn5fBtWxCDEcobWeQQxXHpxJR` is incorrect.

When you send SPL tokens, the `source` and `dest` must be addresses of token accounts, and in this case, `sPkypr2LBtF5Go87zYSn5fBtWxCDEcobWeQQxXHpxJR` is a wallet, so you'll need to create a recipient account for this wallet.

The preferred standard is to use an associated token account, created using something like `create_associated_token_account` from the SPL part of solana-py client: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/2c45353cb510bfeb7259fa19dacbaefe6b9ae3d1/src/spl/token/client.py#L173

For reference, the most important part is creating the instruction to create the associated token account:

```
def create_associated_token_account(payer: PublicKey, owner: PublicKey, mint: PublicKey) -> TransactionInstruction:
    associated_token_address = PublicKey.find_program_address(
        seeds=[bytes(owner), bytes(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID), bytes(mint)], program_id=ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    )
    return TransactionInstruction(
        keys=[
            AccountMeta(pubkey=payer, is_signer=True, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=associated_token_address, is_signer=False, is_writable=True),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=owner, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=mint, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=SYS_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
            AccountMeta(pubkey=SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        ],
        program_id=ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    )
```

More background information about associated token accounts at https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account